# WebRTC video calling and audio calling not working only chat works?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, ratchet

I am using source code from github: https://github.com/amirsanni/Video-Call-App
I want two devices to communicate with each other while they are connected in same wifi network and i have  a local server in the same network without internet. 
Chat is working but audio and video are not working?

Comment: Provide more info (like console logs/offer/answer). Are you using https or not, calls won't work in http.

Comment: Not using any https,Have done the same as done in github example

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with http. Https solved the problem. It seems that the microphone and the camera are not activated by http.

Comment: Indeed. getUserMedia is only available on secure https websites